# Insert ellipsis character inside twig object using &hellip

Tags: html, twig

I am shortening two strings using twig that is over x characters. I want to add ellipsis if the strings get shortened. How do I do this rather than use three periods?

```
{ 
{ title | length > 5 ? title|slice(0,27) ~ &hellip : title }},     
{{dept | length > 5 ? title|slice(0,27) ~ '...' :dept } 
}
```

Edit: bonus issue: how can I only add the comma if the title string is not empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML code should be a string and the output should be not encoded, as example:

```
<h1>
{{ (title | length > 5 ? title|slice(0,5) ~ "&hellip;" : title)|raw }}
</h1>
```

A working example in this fiddle [here](https://twigfiddle.com/t0c8vu)